# Either way the same

Tags: word, knowledge, language

Fill in the blanks to find two longest words of their own kind:

__ __ __ __ V __ __ __ __

__ __ __ __ V __ __ __ __

What is the theme ?

Comment: There are *tons* of possibilities though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are the intended answers:

> ```
> REDIVIDER
> ROTAVATOR
> ```

In that case, the theme is:

> English palindromic words with **V** in the centre (or that have **R** at the ends).
>
>  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome#Long_palindromes) lists them as some of the longest single word palindromes, behind *tattarrattat* (an onomatopoeia), *detartrated* (a chemical term), and tied with *Malayalam* (an Indian language).

Comment: Yes, you got them correct.